# Anonymous type property setters

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, anonymous-types

Why do anonymous types not have property setters?

```
var a = new { Text = "Hello" };
a.Text = "World"; //error
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Anonymous types are immutable by design.

Anonymous types are meant to hold values, and a type that represents a value should not be mutable.

Also, it would make them unreliable in a dictionary, as the hashcode could change after creation.
Many LINQ methods use Dictionaries, and, especially with delayed evaluation, LINQ with mutable types can lead to subtle mysterious bugs.

Comment: Note that anonymous types in VB are allowed to be partially mutated. In VB you get to state which parts of the anonymous type are mutable; the generated code will not use mutable bits as part of a hash code / equality, so you don't get the "lost in the dictionary" problem.  We decided to not implement these extensions in C#.

Comment: If you use C# 10+, you can use with keyword for this purpose. For more information, you can read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76170430/8810311