# change value of a member of a list of type anonymous

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, dynamic

I have a list of anonymous objects, that each anonymous object has the same members, and I create this list by something like this :

```
var listWorthies = balanceWorthies.Select(w => new
                        {
                            OwnerName = w.OwnerOnInquery,
                            OwnerDocDate = w.OwnerDocDate,
                        }).ToList();
```

Now I just wanted to convert the *OwnerDocDate* member of each dynamic object.
something like this :

```
    var listWorthies = balanceWorthies.Select(w => new
                        {
                            OwnerName = w.OwnerOnInquery,
                            OwnerDocDate = ConvertDate(w.OwnerDocDate),
                        }).ToList();
```

gives me the error

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ConvertDate(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

after creating the list, I tried somethings like these ones too :

```
                  foreach (dynamic Worthy in listWorthies)
                        {
                         DateTime OwnerDocDate_2 = ConvertDate(Worthy.OwnerDocDate);
                         Worthy.AddProperty(OwnerDocDate_2);
                        }
```

but it gives me this error :

*'<>f__AnonymousType8<string,string,System.DateTime,System.DateTime,System.Guid,string>' does not contain a definition for 'AddProperty'*

**UPDATE**

the output of function *ConvertDate* is String, and I want to change the type of OwnerDocDate from *datetime* to *string*.

how can I solve this?

Comment: What's the type of the original field "OwnerDocDate" ?
Could you copy/paste the exact exception message please ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441420/how-to-set-value-for-property-of-an-anonymous-object... I'd strongly recommend [edit] the post to show where "dynamic" items come into play  - so far code only shows *anonymous types*.

Comment: @Aliz, I've Updated my question.

Comment: There is no reason to use `dynamic` in the `foreach` with the questionable `AddProperty`. You need to tell us what version of EF you are using: LINQ to EF 6.x / EF 2.0 / 2.1 / EF Core 3.x ?

Comment: @NetMage, I'm Using EF 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell us that balanceWorthies is an `IQueryable<...>`, not an `IEnumerable<...>`.

To understand why this matters, you must understand the difference between an `IQueryable<...>`, and an `IEnumerable<...>`.

### IEnumerable

An object of a class that implements `IEnumerable<...>`, represents a sequence. You can get the first element, and once you've got an element, you can get the next element, as long as there are elements.

At its lowest level this is done using methode `GetEnumerator() / MoveNext() / Current`:

```
IEnumerable<Cusotmer> customers = ...
IEnumerator<Customer> enumerator = customers.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // There is still a Customer in the sequence:
    Customer customer = enumerator.Current;
    ProcessCustomer(customer);
}
```

`foreach`  will deep inside do this.

If you look at the LINQ methods, you will see that there are two groups of methods: the ones that return `IEnumerable<...>` and the others. The first group won't enumerate the sequence. We say that they use lazy-execution or deferred-execution. In the description of these LINQ methods, you'll find this term in the remarks section.

Concatenating methods of this group isn't expensive: the query is not executed, only the Enumerator is adjusted.

The LINQ methods that return something else than `IEnumerble<...>` will execute the sequence. Deep inside `GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current` is called to access the elements of the source sequence one by one.

### IQueryable

An object of a class that implements `IQueryable<...>` doesn't represent an enumerable sequence, it represents the **potential** to fetch an enumerable sequence.

To do this, the class holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression holds what data must be fetched in some generic format. The Provider knows where the data must be fetched (usually a Database Management System) and what language is used to communicate with this DBMS (usually SQL).

When you ask the IQueryable to get the enumerator, the Expression is sent to the Provider, who will translate the Expression into SQL and fetch the data at the DBMS. The fetched data is presented as an `IEnumerator<...>`. The caller can use `MoveNext() / Current` to access the fetched elements one by one.

### Back to your question

The Provider doesn't know your own methods. Hence it doesn't know how to translate them into SQL. In fact, there are several standard LINQ methods that are not supported by entity framework. See [Supported and unsupported LINQ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Your compiler doesn't know how smart your Provider is, so he can't complain. You'll get the error at runtime.

The easiest way to solve your problem is by transferring the data to your local process and let your local process execute the methods as if it was an `IEnumerable<...>`.

This is done using the method `Enumerable.AsEnumerable`. As transferring data is expensive, it is wise to limit the data being transferred to a minimum before you call AsEnumerable. So first do all your `Where, (Group-)Join`, etc. everything that limits the amount of transferred data.

```
var listWorthies = balanceWorthies.Select(w => new
{
    OwnerName = w.OwnerOnInquery,
    OwnerDocDate = w.OwnerDocDate,
})

// OwnerDocDate has the type of balanceWorthy.OwnerDocDate
// move the data to local process, so you can ConvertDate
.AsEnumerable()

// now you can call your own methods:
.Select(fetchedItem => new
{
    OwnerName = fetchedItem.OwnderName,
    OwnerDocDate = ConvertDate(fetchedItem.OwnerDocDate),
});
```

Database management systems are extremely optimized in selecting data. It seems that ConvertDate will only translate the data into a different format. So you won't lose a lot of efficiencies.

If in other cases the method will change the amount of selected data, try to change the expression such that the DBMS can handle it, especially if it is before a Where. If the DBMS must execute your code, and you can't translate the LINQ into something that your provider supports, you'll have to write an extension method that changes the Expression. How to do that is something for a different question.