# How to modify a property of an anynomus type array in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have the following code

```
var result = data.Select(a => new { Id = a.Id, text = a.Type, assetName  = a.Value}).Take(10).OrderBy(a => a.text).ToList();
```

I want to concatenate Type and Value in a single value and assign this value to the text like that

```
foreacah(var item in result)
{
  item.text = item.text + " | " + item.assetName;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value for property of an anonymous object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441420/how-to-set-value-for-property-of-an-anonymous-object)

Comment: You will have to use reflection, or not use anonymous types. Anonymous types are *supposed* to be immutable, though using reflection you can circumvent this. From regular C#, however, you can't.

Comment: Why not just do the concatenate in your ```.Select(a =>```

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous objects are usually used within a create-once and read-once-context. Performing any logic on them doesn´t fit to that concept.

However as you´re iterating that collection anyway, you can also just create another one where you create new objects - that again are readonly.

```
var result = data.Select(a => new { Id = a.Id, text = a.Type, assetName  = a.Value}).Take(10).OrderBy(a => a.text).ToList();
var modified = result.Select(x => new { 
    Id = x.Id,
    text = x.text + "|"  x.assetName },
    assetName = x.AssetName 
});
```

Comment: I'm iterating the collection in order to modify the results.

Comment: @AlexT sure, but it makes no real difference, if you modifiy the existing objects or just clone them in order to give the clones other properties.